# How to show VIF

Tags: regression, econometrics, r-squared, variance-inflation-factor

The variance of the $j$th element of the OLS estimator is given by

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\beta}_{j}\right)=\sigma^{2}\left(X_{j}^{T} M_{-j} X_{j}\right)^{-1}$$

where $X_j$ is the column of regressors associated to the $j$ variable, and $M_{-j}$ is the maker of residuals (the projection off) of the space generated by all columns of the matrix $X$ besides the $j$th one.

Show that the variance of $\hat{\beta}$ can also be written as

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{\beta}_{j}\right)=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{(n-1) \operatorname{Var}\left(X_{j}\right)}\left(\frac{1}{1-R_{X_{j} \mid X_{-j}}^{2}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that (see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390064/can-adjusted-r-squared-be-equal-to-1/390143#390143)), in general,
$$
R^2=1-\frac{\hat{u}'\hat{u}}{\tilde{y}'\tilde{y}}.
$$
Here, $\hat u$ denotes the vector of residuals and $\tilde y$ the vector of demeaned observations on the dependent variable.

In matrix notation, with dependent variable $X_j$, the numerator is just
$$
X_{j}^{T} M_{-j} X_{j}
$$
and the denominator is sum of the squares of the demeaned observations of the $X_j$, i.e., $n-1$ its sample variance (which I prefer to denote by $s^2_{X_j}$ to make clear it is not the population variance of $X_j$).

Thus,
$$
R_{X_{j} \mid X_{-j}}^{2}=1-\frac{X_{j}^{T} M_{-j} X_{j}}{(n-1)s^2_{X_j}}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)s^2_{X_j}}\frac{1}{1-R_{X_{j} \mid X_{-j}}^{2}}=(X_{j}^{T} M_{-j} X_{j})^{-1}
$$