# Is there any hypothesis testing involving pseudo R-squared?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit

Is there any hypothesis testing involving pseudo R-squared?

I mean the equation of test statistic or pdf.

For example, these pseudo R-squared.

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm

Comment: Could you explain a little what sort of tests you had in mind? Many of the pseudo-$R^2$s are just re-expressions of the likelihood ratio comparing the fitted model & the null model.

Comment: @Scortchi♦ , I mean any tests derived from pseudo R-squared. For example, F test can be derived form R-squared.

Comment: As in [Whats the relationship between R2 and F-Test?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56881/17230)?

Comment: @Scortchi♦ , yes. I seldom see pseudo R-squareds are used in test statistic or pdf.