# Is there such a thing as a too low R-squared when running multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, r-squared

This is a very general question about R-squared or the coefficient of determination. I found a couple of threads on CV but none that answers my question in a straightforward way.

In short, **what is a ‘low’ R-squared when running multiple linear regression?** From which minimum value should we conclude that our model does not make better than the baseline?

I sometimes see R-squared values that are as low as 0.15, yet the models are significant. I guess this depends on size, on whether R-squared is used for prediction or inference, etc., however I still do not have a good intuition for it.

It also seems to me that in the ‘hard’ sciences, R-squared tend to be high (say, 0.8 or higher in classic cases), whereas in the social sciences, from what I can see, it tends to be lower (say, under 0.5). I know this might be a gross generalization, however.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/is-my-model-any-good-based-on-the-diagnostic-metric-r2-auc-accuracy-rmse/414350#414350)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what $R^2$ means: proportion of variability explained, compared to a baseline model that always guesses the average value of the pooled response variable.

If you’re higher than $R^2=0$, which you probably will be with in-sample data when you use an intercept, then you’re beating the baseline performance.

Comment: Many thanks @Dave. This I get, yes. My question is more about what we can consider to be a low/bad R-squared? Likewise, can we really say that our model is better than the baseline when R-squared is, say, 0.1? I know 0.1 is better than 0, yet can we say that such a model is helpful to answer a research question, for example? I was also wondering why in tutorials we see R-squared of 0.9 or higher, yet in real life (say, when doing actual research), we rarely see such as high R-squared. But maybe my question is too naive?

Comment: $0.1>0$, so a model getting $R^2=0.1$ is better than the baseline. “Good enough” is going to depend on the task, but you probably aren’t comparing your performance to the intercept-only model but to competing models made by rival groups (think Citi vs Bank of America). // I don’t care for $R^2$ for this reason. For model comparison, it contains no information beyond what you get from MSE (assuming the same data), and it puts us in a position to equate scores to letter grades in school where $R^2>0.9$ is an $A$, $0.9>R^2>0.8$ is a $B$ etc, when $R^2=0.2$ might be excellent (consider t-testing).

Comment: thanks @Dave, indeed it contains same info as MSE (which is also why I was wondering what the rationale of R-squared is). The idea that it can be used for comparisons between models/competitors rather than per se or with intercept-only model is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is no - without more context, we can never simply look at the $R^2$ value of a model and say "this is good enough" or "this is bad" aside from the (somewhat trivial) case of $R^2 > 0$. As Dave point's out, $R^2$ contains no more information than the MSE.

As an example that helps illustrate why this is the case, see [section 3.2 of these notes](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/10/lecture-10.pdf), which points out that among other annoying properties of $R^2$, we have:

> $R^2$ can be arbitrarily low when the model is completely correct. ... By making $Var[X]$ small, or $\sigma^2$ large, we drive $R^2$ towards 0, even when every assumption of the simple linear regression model is correct in every particular.

So a linear model which captures a true linear relationship *correctly* may still have an arbitrarily low $R^2$ if the residual noise is large. This is one of the reason we see different $R^2$ in different settings, like physics laboratories vs econometric analyses - there are (among other differences) probably different levels of residual noise, even when we have a model that is correctly specified.

Comment: many thanks @ Louis Cialdella, this is very helpful. Thanks for the notes as well, these are very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Statistical significance (rejecting the null hypothesis of zero regression coefficients) involves the observed $R^2$ and the sample size $n$. Under certain assumptions, for small $R^2$ and large $n$, the significance approximately depends on the product $R^2 n$; this can be seen for the correlation coefficient significance in [simple regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student%27s_t-distribution) and for the $F$-test in [multiple regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56881/213173). This indicates that even subtle effects (small $R^2$) can be measured with significance given a large enough sample. Intuitively, the larger the sample, the more averaging occurs in calculating $R^2$ and the more the "noise" is reduced in comparison to the "signal".

Comment: thanks @nanoman

Answer (score 2):

The $R^2$ can be interpreted as a percentage of variation in the $y$ that is explained by the regression. This is not in the first place about the question whether the $x$-variables have an influence or not (although there is a mathematical relation, as pointed out in another answer) as opposed to significance tests, and neither is it about whether linearity holds. What can be said is that a model with low $R^2$ will not allow to predict very precisely, and it indicates that the modelled influence of the $x$-variables is rather weak compared to variability coming from whatever other sources. There are no fixed cut-off values, as it depends on the application how much precision is required. A model with $R^2=0.1$ can be good if a substantial practical advantage can be achieved by predicting $y$ even very roughly from $x$, whereas $R^2=0.7$ may be low if there is a requirement to control $y$ strongly given $x$. You can give yourself more intuition just looking at a number of two- or low dimensional data sets and their $R^2$-values, where you can see how precisely the $y$ are fitted by the model, and how this translates into $R^2$.

Note that $R^2$ is computed on the training data, and its relation to prediction quality will (apart from the linearity assumption) depend on the number of $x$-variables, for which reason there is "adjusted $R^2$".