# What could cause the F-statistic to increase but adjusted $R^2$ to decrease?

Tags: multiple-regression, r-squared, f-statistic

I have created two multiple linear models of the same data. The two models vary only in the dropping of a few variables.

Model_A includes all X independent vars (A,B,C,D):
[image]

Model_B includes only A,B as C,D were found to be insignificant:
[image]

As you can see the F-statistic has decreased but the adjusted R^2 has decreased. My understanding is that F and R should increase concurently. Can anyone explain these results?

Comment: What makes you think that F-statisitc and R should increase concurrently?

Comment: In general, the $F$ statistic too often can **decrease** when the number of predictors increases.  That's because $F$ normalizes for the number of predictor degrees of freedom $p$ by dividing sums of squares regression by $p$.  $\chi^2$ statistics $\uparrow$ as $p \uparrow$ so the $\chi^2$ statistic is perhaps a better basis for judgment.  This is bolstered by the fact that for the linear model the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ statistic is exactly $-n \times \log(1 - R^{2})$.

Comment: @Michael Simply look at the [formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/56884/805) relating $F$ to $R^{2}$ and notice that it's something times a monotonic function of $R^{2}$. That 'something' encompasses a complete answer to the question.